# How do I initialize mydatabase.db SQLite file in Azure wwwroot?

Tags: sqlite, azure

I have an API app hosted in Azure. Using the Azure console, I was able to `touch mydatabase.db`. How do I run my sql script on this file to create the tables, etc? There is no sqlite client in the Azure console CLI. Is there some other tool i should use to connect?

I would prefer a macOS friendly solution.

Comment: This is not a sql-azure question, but I cannot edit the tags at the moment.

Comment: Alright.. what should I set the tags?